# Is it Possible to RDP into a BootCamp Image running Windows 8.1?

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp

I have forwarded a port on my router to my Mac mini OS X server which is running OS X and Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp.  Can I remote into the BootCamp image using remote desktop or VNC?  If so, what settings must be changed to accomplish this?

Comment: So long as you're currently booted into Windows, yes.  The settings aren't any different than remoting into any other Windows box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use RDC all the time and I know a few things about it. I have a similar setup as you, Apple based server but with a windows 8 partition. I RDC into the partition from another Mac and it all works fine. Here are a couple links that should help you with the setup on your Windows. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/remote-desktop-connection-faq#1TC=windows-7 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKUcU4KBb8s. This should help you get up and running. The setup I have on the Mac is the Domain is the internal IP that you will get from your Windows and obviously the Username and password... are the username and password to your Windows. Hope I haven't been too blunt, but feel free to ask for help.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, but so long as Windows 8.1 is running at the time you want to RDP to it.

If you need to have both running, my suggestion is to install Windows in a Virtual Machine so they are both running simultaneously.

Check out [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org) for a good free solution.

If you needs some tips/pointers on how to setup up, just let me know.